# Drupal sending out unwanted emails about new content

Tags: emails

I am receiving tons of Mail Delivery System failed regarding new content notifications.

Looks like my website is sending out new content notification to every registered user.

But I never set up such behaviour, and I don't want my users to receive updates this way.

This is going on since 1 week, have to find a solution.

---[Here below one of the thousands of the returning message:]---

This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

```
 name@gmail.com
   SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data:
   host p3nlsmtpcp-v01.prod.phx3.gdg [72.167.191.78]:
   552 5.2.0 q6pN1p00w4NPGeA01 :: CPANEL :: Message rejected for spam or virus content ::
   Please include this entire message when contacting support ::
   v=2.1 cv=O7y3vXNW c=1 sm=1 tr=0 p=65lisdlOQaQA:10 p=9sfF_i041VMA:10 a=GrLZr1+P9ClXUG4p+qBB1A==:117 a=GrLZr1+P9ClXUG4p+qBB1A==:17 a=TZb1taSUAAAA:8 a=h0rLbXwqTyIA:10 a=IkcTkHD0fZMA:10 a=60h86PuPWa4A:10 a=H9FGv8k8AAAA:8 a=0HtSIViG9nkA:10 a=e4lbWNnZ9XO776ZxNvwA:9 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10 ::
   97.00
```

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

```
Return-path: <me@mywebsite.com>
Received: from my na by p3plcpnl0675.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with local (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <me@mywebsite.com>)
    id 0002fW-5m
    for name@gmail.com; Sun, 08 Feb 2015 23:52:06 -0700
To: name@gmail.com
Subject: New content notification for name from mywesite
X-PHP-Script: www.massamagra.com/index.php for 123.124.125.126
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
X-Mailer: Drupal
From: me@mywebsite.com
Message-Id: <E1YKiCU-0002fW-5m@p3plcpnl0675.prod.phx3.secureserver.net>
Date: Sun, 08 Feb 2015 23:52:06 -0700
```

Greetings name, this is a notification about new content from mywebsite.

This e-mail may only shows excerpts. Click on the links below to see the
whole node/comment.

---[I omitted content here because is full of links to my website]---

This is an automatic e-mail from massamagra.
To stop receiving these e-mails, change your notification preferences at (omitted: link to user)

Comment: May be any subscription is setup. Check rules, trigger or any notification related module. It can be your custom module too.